# Show that the null space of A consists of all points on the z-axis.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that relative to an xyz-coordinate system in 3-space the null
> space of A consists of all points on the z-axis and that the column
> space consists of all points in the xy-plane.
>
> $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

The augmented system of equations for $A\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$ with the first two rows swapped:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Thus, the correspending system of equations show that $x=0$ and $y=0$.

After this, I am not sure how to prove that the null space consists of all points on the z-axis. Intuitively it makes sense. The definition for null space in my textbook states:

> The solution space of the homogeneous system of equations $A\textbf{x}
>  = \textbf{0}$, which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is called the null space of A.

But my book does not give a clear definition for the solution space, so I don't know how to define the solution space in this problem.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the $z$ column belong to the null space, simply multiply matrix $A$ by column vector $[0,0,z]^T$. By doing this you will get a zero vector, and thus $[0,0,z]$ belongs to the null space:

$$ A [0,0,z]^T = 0 [0,1,0]^T + 0 [1,0,0]^T + z [0,0,0]^T = [0,0,0]^T $$

Comment: But I guess what I am missing is how this proves that the z-axis belongs to the null space. Would you be able to explain a bit more in detail?

Comment: The Z-axis can be parameterized by the vector [0,0,z], which means that any element of the z-axis can be written as [0,0,z]. We have shown that the vector [0,0,z] belongs to the null space, therefore, every element of the z-axis belongs to it.